Fetching data from cursor from Postgres stored procedure via ODBC in C
Thank you for your help in advance. I've got a simple SP in Postgres:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SP(INOUT _result_one refcursor = 'rs_resultone')
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $$
BEGIN
  open _result_one for 
   SELECT * 
   FROM (values (1,2,3, 'fruit', current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5 seconds'), (4,5,6, 'veggie', current_timestamp)) as t(a,b,c,d,e);
END;
$$;

I'm able to call it in pgAdmin without any problem.
CALL test_get_data_single();
FETCH ALL FROM "rs_resultone";

"a","b","c","d","e"
1,2,3,"fruit","2024-06-24 15:39:54.641594+00"
4,5,6,"veggie","2024-06-24 15:39:59.641594+00"

However, I've got issue with fetching data in C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STORED_PROCEDURE "TEST_SP" 

void check_sql_code(int sql_code, char *message, SQLHDBC dbc, SQLHENV env, SQLHSTMT stmt) {
  if (sql_code != SQL_SUCCESS) {
    SQLINTEGER   error_code;
    SQLSMALLINT  message_length;
    SQLCHAR      sql_state[6];
    SQLCHAR      error_message[1024];
    SQLRETURN    ret;
    SQLINTEGER   i = 0;

    printf("Err[%d]: %s", sql_code, message);

    do {
      ret = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt, ++i, sql_state, &error_code, error_message, sizeof(error_message), &message_length);
      printf("%s:%d:%d:%s\n", sql_state, i, error_code, error_message);
    } while( ret == SQL_SUCCESS );    
    
    if (stmt != NULL) SQLFreeStmt(stmt, SQL_CLOSE);
    SQLDisconnect(dbc);
    SQLFreeConnect(dbc);
    SQLFreeEnv(env);
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main() {
  SQLHENV env;
  SQLHDBC dbc;
  SQLHSTMT stmt;
  SQLRETURN ret; /* ODBC API return status */
  SQLCHAR outstr[1024];
  SQLSMALLINT outstrlen;
  SQLHSTMT cursor_stmt; // Handle for cursor statement
  SQLSMALLINT num_cols;
  SQLCHAR col_name[128]; // Buffer for column name
  SQLSMALLINT col_name_len;  
  char sql_statement[256];

  SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);                /* Allocate an environment handle */
  SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);  /* We want ODBC 3 support */
  SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);                            /* Allocate a connection handle */
  ret = SQLDriverConnect(dbc, NULL, "DSN=TEST_DB;", SQL_NTS, outstr, sizeof(outstr), &outstrlen, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE); /* Connect to the DSN mydsn */
  if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
    printf("Connected\n");
    if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
      printf("Driver reported the following diagnostics\n");
      check_sql_code(ret, "SQLDriverConnect", dbc, env, NULL);
    }
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect\n");
    check_sql_code(ret, "SQLDriverConnect", dbc, env, NULL);
  }

  printf("Allocate statement handle\n");
  ret = SQLAllocStmt(dbc, &stmt);
  check_sql_code(ret, "Error allocating statement handle\n", dbc, env, stmt);

  snprintf(sql_statement, sizeof(sql_statement), "CALL %s(1);", STORED_PROCEDURE);

  printf("Execute the SQL statement (to open the cursor)\n");
  ret = SQLExecDirect(stmt, (unsigned char*)sql_statement, SQL_NTS);
  check_sql_code(ret, "Error executing stored procedure\n", dbc, env, stmt);

  printf("Allocate a statement handle for fetching data from the cursor\n");
  ret = SQLAllocStmt(dbc, &cursor_stmt);
  check_sql_code(ret, "Error allocating cursor statement handle\n", dbc, env, cursor_stmt);
  
  printf("Prepare the cursor statement\n");
  ret = SQLPrepare(cursor_stmt, (unsigned char*)"FETCH ALL IN \"rs_resultone\";", SQL_NTS);
  check_sql_code(ret, "Error preparing cursor statement\n", dbc, env, cursor_stmt);

  ret = SQLExecute(cursor_stmt);
  check_sql_code(ret, "Error preparing cursor statement\n", dbc, env, cursor_stmt);
  
  // Fetch data row by row
   while ((ret = SQLFetch(cursor_stmt)) != SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND) {
    check_sql_code(ret, "Error fetching\n", dbc, env, cursor_stmt);
  }

  printf("Disconnect from driver\n");
  SQLDisconnect(dbc);
  check_sql_code(-1, "Disconnecting from database\n", dbc, env, cursor_stmt);
}


I'd like to add that I don't want to use functions, etc. I'd like to just have the equivalent in C code. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Radek
The output of the program:
Connected
Allocate statement handle
Execute the SQL statement (to open the cursor)
Allocate a statement handle for fetching data from the cursor
Prepare the cursor statement
Err[-1]: Error preparing cursor statement
34000:1:1:ERROR: cursor "rs_resultone" does not exist;
Error while executing the query
00000:2:1:ERROR: cursor "rs_resultone" does not exist;
Error while executing the query


You must call the procedure and fetch from the cursor in the same database transaction.

The hint received from Laurenz helped very much indeed. By default, ODBC enables the auto-commit feature. What's more, it can't be set in odbc.ini. That was my mistake, after setting the connection parameter it started working. Thank you!
